# How to ignore object references reuse from load in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Let's say I have the following Java ORM mapping:

```java
@Entity
public class Person {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne
  private Address workAddress;

  @OneToOne
  private Address homeAddress;

}

@Entity
public class Address {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

}
```

And let's say that a given `Person` instance was created using the same persisted `Address` instance.
For example:

```java
@Transactional
public void reuseAddressInPerson() {
   Address address = new Address();
   // fill address values
   address = em.persist(address);
   Person person = new Person();
   person.workAddress = address;
   person.homeAddress = address;
   em.persist(person);
}
```

Based on that, when I load this persisted `person` using hibernate, the address instances for `workAddress` and `homeAddress` will be the same reference in the `person` object.
There is some way to make hibernate create new instances for each `address` object when calling `em.find()`?

Note: I have created this example illustrated my question, but in the real scenario it is not practical to use clone (or something similar) to prepare this object.

Comment: What's your real scenario, because in this case it's working correctly and any other behaviour would be buggy.

Comment: after `em.persist` you could try `em.refresh(person)`. That discards whats in memory and requeries the database for new information which will also create the new objects in the model

Comment: I have a scenario that executes engineering calculations based on a product model. In this scenario some entities are reused accross the product model and therefore they must be different references to execute the calculation, in the other case one component can interferes in the other. During the calculation time, the entities IDs are not relevant for the calcuation (could be defined as null) and therefore the same database objects must be different references in memory.

Comment: Why must they be different references? Are you mutating the entities? Your problem is that you're sharing entities, yet you don't want them to be shared. So it's a design problem, more than a programming problem.

Comment: Yes, lets me use the example of a bicycle. The calculation could starts using a product model where the front and back wheels are the same in database. But given the user requirements, the calculation changes the diameter of the front wheel. In this case, the original product model was using to the same wheel object ID in both front and back wheel at the calculation start. However, during calculation the front wheel was changed, in this case if the front and back wheels are the same references, then back wheel will be get inconsistent.

Comment: I don't think it's a desing problem. The point is that in database I'm trying to reuse objects that share the same characteristics, but during executing time the objects can change. What could be a better design for this kind of scenario?

Comment: @JoãoPedroSchmitt At least a design smell. Your options are to either start with distinct entities, so you never get the problem in the first place, or to copy-on-mutate, which will make your code more complex. Unless you have a **real** reason (something that doesn't start with "I want" or "I think") to share the entities, I would go with distinct entities from the start. Otherwise you'll be fighting Hibernate and most likely spending some time debugging weird bugs.

Comment: Hm.. I understood your point. The reason is because in ERP system the material (id of entity) must be unique for production componentes (entities with the same characteristics). I didn't told it before, but for now the save method already has a processing step where I search for componentes base on their values (Using the Example API of spring-data).

Comment: In JPA, you can't have multiple instances of the same `@Id` in the same persistence context, so if you map `Address` to entity you have no option like this, You then have 2 solutions, either detach the entities, clone them, make the calculations and then persist them again, or -as you already said- if you don't care that the calculations have identifiers, why to store them as entities? you can store it as embeddables (no identifier)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, hibernate doesn't provide any out-of-box mechanism to manage entities references. Therefore, I found a way to do this using the `ObjectOutputStream`.
This engine requires two steps, the first loads the entity from database and clear the persistence context, and the second searches in the object structure what entities should clonned to evict shared references.
To explain how it works, we will use the same person-address model from the question.

Step 1 - Loading the entity

```java
public Person loadProject() {
  // First we load person from database
  Person person = personRepository.getOne(personId);
  // Then we clear the persistence context to evict detached exceptions
  entityManager.clear();
  person = (Person) Hibernate.unproxy(person); // Remove proxies from the object
  // Now we call Step 2 (clone shared references)
  person = entityReferencesService.cloneAddressReferences(person);
  return person;
}
```

Step 2 - Clone shared references

```java
public class EntityReferencesService {
  //...
  public Person cloneAddressReferences(Person person) {
    try {
      ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos) {
        {
          enableReplaceObject(true); // Allows objects to be replaced during serialization
        }
        @Override
        protected Object replaceObject(Object obj) throws IOException {
          Object replacedObject = obj;
          // This code could be smart to known what entities to clone
          if (obj instanceof Person) {
            Person p = (Person) obj;
            // using apache bean commons
            p.workAddress = SerializationUtils.clone(p.workAddress);
            p.homeAddress = SerializationUtils.clone(p.homeAddress);
          }
          return replacedObject;
        }
      };
      oos.writeObject(person);
      ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
      ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
      return (Person) ois.readObject();
    } catch (Exception ex) {}
  }
}
```

This example is over-simplified. But for complex scenarios, in the `replaceObject` method, this code should use interfaces or annotations to known what entities clone.